# Big O of calculating reminders

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

Can anyone help me?

Not a homework problem. Just trying to finish all the book problem in my spring break. 
This is from my abstract algebra/Number theory book.

Show that we can compute (a $mod n_1$,...,a $mod n_k)$in time $$O(len(n)^2)$$

where $$n = n_1 *,.......,*n_k$$

given:

$O$ of computing  $q :=  ⌊a/n⌋ $ and $r = a\mod n $ is $O(len(q).len(n))$

$r$ can be written as $a-nq=r$

Book also vaguely says "time to compute q and r is rougly same as time to compute $n\times q$"

Thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @AlexisOlson, My question is to show that we can compute bunch of remainder  (a mod n1, ......., a mod nk) in O (len(n)^2